# paper by Nakata on 2-adic Galois representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

In Keisuke Arai's 2007 paper "On uniform lower bound of the Galois images associated to elliptic curves", which can be found on ArXiv, Arai makes the following citation:

K. Nakata.  *On the 2-adic representation associated to an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$*.  (Japanese), Number Theory Symposium in Kinosaki, December 1979, 221-235.

Arai says that the Galois action on the 2-adic Tate module of a non-CM curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ whose 2-torsion points are all defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ is studied in the above article.

The problem is that this article seems completely inaccessible to me, even after asking the help of several librarians.  In addition, I can't read Japanese, so it's possible that getting hold of the article would be useless for me anyway.

So I'm wondering, can anyone here either somehow point me to a copy of the article (in English), or at least state the main results concerning 2-adic representations associated to elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ which can be found in the article?  Thanks very much!

Comment: This paper seems likely to be hard to find. It's not in MathSciNet, and math genealogy only lists one math Ph.D. with the name K. Nakata. This is a certain Keiko Nakata who earned a Ph.D. in 2007 and works in theoretical computer science.

Comment: Part of the reason for my concern is that I happen to have written a paper about $2$-adic Galois representations for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$. (There's a preprint [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5997).)

Comment: Jeremy, so just to be clear, you don't know anything about what Nakata proved in this paper?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the K. Nakata we're looking for can't be Keiko Nakata...

Comment: @Jeff-I do not know anything about what Nakata proved in this paper.

Comment: @Jeremy Well, I'll let you know if I find anything out, thanks for your comments and link.

Answer (score 1):

This revision (June 2015) is mostly to say that I've verified the answer by ell.  I found the Proceedings volume in question in the U. Tokyo library.  It is basically a bound volume of photocopies of handwritten notes in Japanese.  I made a "scan" with my phone, so if you want a copy of the Japanese version, just ask.  The main theorems are identical, but the arguments in the English version are substantially more detailed, and the list of references was expanded.

---

Old Partial answer: You can find a copy at [one of the libraries listed here](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/ncid/BA63852494?l=en).  If I don't forget, I can take a look late next month when I go to U. Tokyo for a conference.  You can also [buy a copy of the proceedings](http://www.meirinkanshoten.com/book.asp?id=472611) for 4500 Yen (plus shipping).

Answer (score 1):

Kumiko Nishioka  is right name. Please take a look the folloing paper 
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jmsj/1230396544.